# Why are the histograms not of the same size?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in python. I want to resize 2 given images to some fixed value, say (100,100), and then compare their histograms. Why are the histograms not of the same length in this case? can i do something to make them of the same length?

CODE:

```
import os,sys
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('Untitled.png')
I1 = im.resize((100,100))
im2 = Image.open('Untitled2.png')
I2 = im2.resize((100,100))
X = I1.histogram()
Y = I2.histogram()
```

now in the shell, when i check the length of the 2 histograms:

```
>>> len(X)
1024
>>> len(Y)
768
```

Why does this happen even after i resize them? Can i make their lengths equal, without making it the EXACT same image?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: perhaps the images are different enough that fewer bands were needed to capture all of the data in `I2`

Comment: I included the code and output. I just want to compare the 2 histograms, but for that i want them to be of the same length for parsing over. I cant understand why 2 imaged of the same size will have different lengths, because the histogram() function is supposed to return a value for each pixel. Does resizing not fix the pixel count in any image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histograms work based on the number of color bands that an image has. If the image has more than one band, the histograms for all bands are concatenated (for example, the histogram for an “RGB” image contains 768 values).

Try converting image1 to RGB

```
I1rgb = I1.convert('RGB')
```